# Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null

Tags: html, angular, web, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm newbie in Angular and a big sorry if my question is stupid. I have the following problem:

I have  and  worked as required and the problem does not affect the behavior of the app: the app builds, starts and works fine despite the compilation error "Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null" on my component
[The compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vmv2.png)

My package.json:

```
  {
  "name": "shopping-store",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.39",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

and my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CartComponent } from './cart/cart.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatGridListModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The env is Angular IDE by Webclipse...

Comment: Change the import to `import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material';` and reload the dev server

Comment: Thank you for your response! It works fine now